# Are there data modelling tools available for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

This question comes up quite often. For those who are new to Cassandra and particularly to data modelling, what tools are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tools that help Cassandra users design and manage schema.

[**Hackolade**](https://hackolade.com/) is a visual data modelling software for NoSQL and other multi-model databases. It comes with an out-of-the-box plugin that allows you to connect to [Apache Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/) and [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) (DSE) clusters.

[**DataStax DevCenter**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcAbout.html) is a visual IDE for Apache Cassandra. It allows users to manage schema, build and execute CQL queries, and view results in tabular form. Features include CQL syntax highlighting and CQL command auto-completion. It is free to download from the [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#devcenter) site.

[**DataStax Studio**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/studio/docs/aboutStudio.html) is a notebook-style visual tool for CQL, Spark SQL and DSE Graph. Users can build and run CQL queries against DSE clusters and [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra). Users can also perform Gremlin graph traversals, and write/test/run Spark SQL queries against DSE clusters.

Noting here that **Kashliev Data Modeler** (KDM) is an automated data modeling tool for Apache Cassandra which allowed users to easily browse a cluster's schema. However, KDM doesn't appear to be available anymore and the website appears to have been taken down.

Keep an eye on the [Ecosystem](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/ecosystem.html) page at the official [Apache Cassandra website](https://cassandra.apache.org) and Anant Corporation's [cassandra.tools](https://cassandra.tools/) for the curated list of tools. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: The KDM tool can be accessed here: http://kdm.kashliev.com